# How to colorize kubernetes logs?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, kubectl

It's easy enough to enable [colorful logs on docker containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33493456/docker-bash-prompt-does-not-display-color-output) (by setting `TERM=xterm-256color` and running with `tty: True`).

Still, I'm not getting any color when I run `kubectl logs`/`stern`  on the corresponding pods in my cluster.

What am I missing?